# Ensure that all pages of a tab control are clicked before closing form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I've got a form with 8 pages and I'd like to ensure that all the pages are clicked (ie. filled out) before the user can close the form.

And I've got a subform on one of the pages that is a tab control with 2 pages. What I want to do is make sure that the user has filled out (clicked on) both pages before the main form can close.

I don't really know the best way to go about this.

What I've got so far is:

```
Private Sub tabcontrol_Change()
    If (tabcontrol.value = 1) Then
        page2clicked = True
    End If
End Sub
```

And this records if the second page of the subform was clicked or not. But I don't know what to do with this to prevent the main form from closing.

I could also use this for the 8 pages on the main form but I don't know if this is sufficient or not.

Maybe.... hide the close button?

I'm open to any ideas of the best way to go about this problem.

Thanks!

EDIT:
If this is not easy (I'm guessing its not) then is there a way to make the 2 tabs on the subform tab control more visible for the user to see?

Comment: Why are you sure that if they clicked it got filled up? I'd loop controls to ensure all required controls aren't empty before closing form (click event in close button)

Comment: Good Idea. But all my controls have a default value and users can just leave them as the default if "no" is the correct answer.
So if I loop through all of the controls will have a value even if the user didn't go to that page.

Comment: You could hide close button and add navigation buttos (prev next) and show close button in last page

Comment: How would I show the close button only on the last page?

Comment: me.CloseButton=False on load event. When user reaches last page me.CloseButton=true.

Comment: That gives me an error - "To set this property, open the form or report in Design view"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55864/discussion-between-horaciux-and-victoria).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide close buton in design view.

```
CloseButton=False
```

Add a new button in last page. This new button should close the form in click event.